# How can I find the hardware specifications for Android Automotive OS vehicles?

Tags: android-automotive

While looking into developing for Android Automotive OS, specifically within the [parked apps categories](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/parked), I've found it hard to know what the range of hardware available looks like.

Unlike phones/tablets, most of the OEMs don't post the hardware specifications for their screens/CPUs/RAM/etc. on their product pages. And some of the screens are also at uncommon aspect ratios that are much wider than phones/tablets.

Does anyone know an easy way to get these specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the Play Console Device Catalog, [this search](https://play.google.com/console/developers/app/devices?mode=allDevices&formFactor=FORM_FACTOR_AUTO) will show you a list of all of the cars with Google built-in and you can either use the results in that table or export a CSV with all of the specs for those devices.

[image]

Below is the export from today:

```
Brand,Device,Manufacturer,Model Name,RAM (TotalMem),Form Factor,System on Chip,GPU,Screen Sizes,Screen Densities,ABIs,Android SDK Versions,OpenGL ES Versions,Install base
gm,gminfo37,General Motors,Infotainment 3.7,5801MB,Android Automotive,Intel A3960,Intel HD Graphics 500 (750 MHz),768x1280,160,x86_64,29,3.2,0
renault,aivi2_full,Renault,OpenR Link,8058MB,Android Automotive,Qualcomm SM8150,Qualcomm Adreno 640 (585 MHz),1250x1562,160,arm64-v8a,29,3.2,0
VolvoCars,ihu_abl_car,Volvo,Volvo,3914-8135MB,Android Automotive,Intel A3960,Intel HD Graphics 500 (750 MHz),768x1024,140,x86_64,30,3.2,0
Phoenix,belford,Nautilus,Digital Experience,12498MB,Android Automotive,Qualcomm SA8155P,Qualcomm Adreno 640 (700 MHz),1080x2348,240,arm64-v8a,32,3.2,0
Honda,msmnile_au,Honda,IVI-SYSTEM,8061MB,Android Automotive,Qualcomm SA8155P,Qualcomm Adreno 640 (700 MHz),720x1920,160,arm64-v8a,30,3.2,0
gm,aegean,General Motors,aegean,8309MB,Android Automotive,Qualcomm SA8155P,Qualcomm Adreno 640 (700 MHz),974x2000,160,arm64-v8a,30,3.2,0
Polestar,ihu_abl_car,Polestar,Polestar,3911-8133MB,Android Automotive,Intel A3960,Intel HD Graphics 500 (750 MHz),1152x1536;768x1024,180,x86_64,30,3.2,0
```